# Removing negative values and one positive value from R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe where one column is the amount spent.  In the amount spent column there are the values for amount spent and also negative values for any returns. For example.

```
ID    Store    Spent
123    A        18.50
123    A       -18.50
123    A        18.50
```

I want to remove the negative value then one of its positive counter parts - the idea is to only keep fully completed spend amounts so I can look at total spend.

Right now I am thinking something like this - where I have the data frame sorted by spend

```
if spend < 0 {
  take absolute value of spend
  if diff between abs(spend) and spend+1 = 0 then both are NA}
```

I would like to have something like

```
df[df$spend < 0] <- NA
```

where I can also set one positive counterpart to NA as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you know if a given row is a "positive counterpart"? Can you just pick a row at random with matching ID and identical value (sans pos/neg sign)?

Comment: I can delete any of the so called "positive counterparts" .  I am trying to get total spend for all ID's and not by individual ID so if I have a negative value somewhere I just need a positive removed as well.  I don't even need to do this with a dataframe.  I can take the column as a vector and work with that.

Comment: Are you trying to get the net expenditures per store? Or per store-id pairing?

Comment: I already have the data subset by store.  I just need to sum(spend) but want to remove the returns (negative values) and the original transaction associated with that return.  Because I am not containing this to individual ID's I don't necessarily need to remove the actual original transaction that is associated with a return.  Just need to remove the negative value and one positive along with it.

Comment: Is it sufficient to calculate the net expenditure per store?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan You posted a solution using the data.table library and were able to do this but ID number.  I didn't get a chance to use that to see how it works.  Could you post that again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a simpler solution to this but here is one way. Also created my own example since the one shared did not have sufficient data points to test

```
#Original vector
x <- c(1, 2, -2, 1, -1, -1, 2, 3, -4, 1, 4)
#Count the frequency of negative numbers, keeping all the unique numbers
vals <- table(factor(abs(x[x < 0]), levels = unique(abs(x))))   
#Count the frequency of absolute value of original vector
vals1 <- table(abs(x)) 
#Subtract the frequencies between two vectors
new_val <- vals1 - (vals * 2 )
#Recreate the new vector
as.integer(rep(names(new_val), new_val))
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 3):

If you add a rowid column you can do this with data.table ant-joins.

Here's an example which takes ID into account, not deleting "positive counterparts" unless they're the same ID

First create more interesting sample data

```
df <- fread('
ID    Store    Spent
123    A        18.50
123    A       -18.50
123    A        18.50
123    A       -19.50
123    A        19.50
123    A       -99.50
124    A       -94.50
124    A        99.50
124    A        94.50
124    A        94.50
')
```

Now remove all the negative values with positive counterparts, and remove those counterparts

```
negs <- df[Spent < 0][, Spent := -Spent][, rid := rowid(ID, Spent)]
pos <- df[Spent > 0][, rid := rowid(ID, Spent)]
pos[!negs, on = .(ID, Spent, rid), -'rid']
#     ID Store Spent rid
# 1: 123     A  18.5   2
# 2: 124     A  99.5   1
# 3: 124     A  94.5   2
```

And as applied to Ronak's `x` vector example

```
x <- c(1, 2, -2, 1, -1, -1, 2, 3, -4, 1, 4)
negs <- data.table(x = -x[x<0])[, rid := rowid(x)]
pos <- data.table(x = x[x>0])[, rid := rowid(x)]
pos[!negs, on = names(pos), -'rid']

#    x
# 1: 2
# 2: 3
# 3: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code.

```
library(dplyr)
store <- rep(LETTERS[1:3], 3)
id <- c(1:4, 1:3, 1:2)
expense <- runif(9, -10, 10)
tibble(store, id, expense) %>%
  group_by(store) %>%
  summarise(net_expenditure = sum(expense))
```

to get this output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  store net_expenditure
  <chr>           <dbl>
1 A               13.3 
2 B                8.17
3 C               16.6
```

Alternatively, if you wanted the net expenditure per store-id pairing, then you could use this code:

```
tibble(store, id, expense) %>%
  group_by(store, id) %>%
  summarise(net_expenditure = sum(expense))
```

I've approached your question from a slightly different perspective. I'm not sure that my code answers your question, but it might help.